# Okta/Spring Boot Saml application enters infinite loop

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-saml, okta

I followed this guide:

https://dzone.com/articles/get-started-with-spring-boot-saml-and-okta

And everything worked good at first. But then the app enters the infinite loop: in browser's url it redirects to Okta's Sign in page and vice versa. When i clear my browsing data in Chrome by removing cookies everything starts to work fine again. But after sometimes infinite loop rises again. Here's some parts of exception:

```
2018-05-15 20:16:23.027  INFO 11136 --- [nio-8443-exec-1] 
o.s.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger  : AuthNResponse;FAILURE;0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1;https://localhost:8443/saml/metadata;http://www.okta.com/exkezd0f1qtnMMYy90h7;;;org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: Response doesn't have any valid assertion which would pass subject validation
at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:229)
at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(SAMLAuthenticationProvider.java:82)
```

...

```
Caused by: org.springframework.security.authentication.CredentialsExpiredException: Authentication statement is too old to be used with value 2018-05-15T11:46:27.900Z
at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.verifyAuthenticationStatement(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:538)
at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.verifyAssertion(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:306)
at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:214)
... 64 more
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

looks like your server clock is 8.5 hours ahead of UTC and somewhere in the bad code looks to be a check that assumes you're in UTC so the token is 8.5 hours old and is rejected, but the IDP thinks you're already logged in and has a session so just responds back with a new statement each time and the SP rejects it each time over and over.
Correct the clock / figure out where the problem is that this can happen if the system is set up correctly for another timezone?